# Simple "Login Attempt" problem with MessageBox.Show

Tags: c#, login-attempts

Hello
I`m new with C# and I want to make a simple C# pin code program where users could only input 3 times or put in 3 times attempts of pincode and the the program will exit using Application.Exit();

but it seems that the loop is making the MessageBox quite annoying continuously and dont allow users to press or key in button for the next 2 attempts.

Help me pls anyone?

Edited with this but the error of "use of unnasigned local variable of 'pin'" T_T :

```
private int _failedAttempts = 0;


    private void btnEtr_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int pin;

        if (pin != 21)
        {
            if (pin !=21)
            {
                _failedAttempts++;
                MessageBox.Show ("Fail. " + (3 - _failedAttempts) + " attempts more.", "EPIC FAIL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                if(_failedAttempts == 3)
                {                       
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Welcome. Your pin is CORRECT", "CONGRATULATIONS",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are just starting!  Now is the time to swear to never use the variable name "i" again.  NEVER.  Just don't do it!

Comment: hahaha okay. i will the next time. thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you're basically telling the user that they've failed, decreasing the counter, and then telling them they've failed again.

You are not giving them the chance to re-enter the pin number. You need to keep track of the attempts outside of the button click event. Declare a class level variable that will keep track of the attempts.

e.g.

```
private int _failedAttempts = 0;
```

And change your button click to something like:

```
if (pin !=21)
{
  _failedAttempts++;
  MessageBox.Show ("Fail. " + (3 - _failedAttempts) + " attempts more.", "EPIC FAIL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

   if(_failedAttempts == 3)
   {                       
     Application.Exit();
   }
}
```

This lets the user enter the pincode, if it fails, it will display the error message and increase the number of attempts. You should let them enter the pin number again, and let them hit the enter button again. When it hits 3 attempts it will exit.

Comment: should it be `3-failedAttempts`??  not `i`?

Comment: @hogan, sorry, I don't follow. I've gotten rid of `i`. It doesn't need to exist anymore as the counter is called `_failedAttempts` and there is no loop.

Comment: @Brandon, you don't follow?  It was a comment on your original post which had the typo.

Comment: @Hogan, ah. I see, I didn't think anyone saw that. I fixed it within seconds :P But yes, I just copy and pasted the error message, didn't bother reading what it said. That'll teach me >_>

Comment: i dont know if there's something wrong with my visual studio, but ive tried to change my codes into your respective solutions but it seems that it still makes the same problem; repeated messagebox without allowing user to key in again, then close.

Comment: @Rfq, are you sure you're running the updated code? Change the code and hit F5 and it should run in debug mode.

Comment: okay. edited and updated the code. now another problem comes up. it seems when i key in the correct pin which is 21, it reads as a wrong pin code too. blergh

Comment: @Rfq, do you know how to set a breakpoint? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/25/set-or-remove-a-breakpoint-vstipdebug0016.aspx Set a breakpoint on the `if (pin !=21)` line and then hover over `pin` to see what the value is.

Comment: @Brandon -- I'm cracking up over here... everyone made the same mistake on their first code post.  Or everyone copied your first version and changed the variable name...

Comment: i have set it. and tried debugging it. but it seems there's an error? "Use of unnasigned local of variabal of 'pin'" while i have declared that 'int pin'. /sigh

Comment: @Hogan, I hope no one bothered to just copy my answer :P It's more likely that since the MessageBox is irrelevant to the problem at hand  it is just ignored. It is up to the OP to review and finalize the code that they receive from answers on SO.

Comment: @Rfq, update your question with the code as it is now. You shouldn't be getting that error unless your code is different than what you said it is.

Comment: sorry. my mistake. it is correct now. i've checked everything back and i forogt the convert. haha. sorry and thanks a lot brandon. you make my day.

Comment: @Rfq, no problem. There was an error in my earlier code, I should have incremented the _failedAttempts before displaying the error message. I updated my answer. Also, if your problem is fixed please remember you can resolve the question by accepting an answer.

Comment: @Brandon eh okai. i have repaired everything. even checked the resolve question. thanks brandon. you`ve been a great help to newbies like me.

Comment: @Brandon eh btw brandon, could you explain why my codings arent working in the first place?

Comment: @Rfq, the first part of my post pretty much covered it. Your loop was executing all 3 times in a single button click. You weren't giving them a chance to try again. That is why instead of a loop, this one keeps a counter that keeps track of how many times the user will fail to match the pin when they submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a variable outside of the event

```
private int attemptsLeft = 3;

private void btnEtr_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int pin = Convert.ToInt32(txtbox.Text);             

        if (pin !=21)
        {

                MessageBox.Show ("Fail. " + --attemptsLeft  + " attempts more.", "EPIC FAIL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

              if( attemptsLeft == 0 )
              {
                   Application.Exit();
              }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Welcome. Your pin is CORRECT", "CONGRATULATIONS",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean `--attemptsLeft` not `i`??

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have your for loop in correctly used.  You are looping through 3 attempts even though they have only tried once.  Try this:

int counter = 0;

private void btnEtr_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int pin;
        int i;

```
    pin = Convert.ToInt32(txtbox.Text);             

    if (pin !=21)
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Fail. " + counter.toString() + " attempts more.", "EPIC FAIL",                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        counter += 1;

        if (counter = 3)
            {                       
                Application.Exit();
            }
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Welcome. Your pin is CORRECT", "CONGRATULATIONS",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

This way you are counting the number of times the person has pressed the button.  Make sure your counter is in your main method so that it keeps a record of your tries

Comment: @Hogan I don't see an "i" in my counter.  I have "counter += 1"

Comment: @bvandrunen nope. in the messagebox has an "i". tried this though, not working. but thanks anyway. i appreciate it :)

Comment: @bvandrunen:  Line 5.  The string that is passed to messagebox show.

Comment: @Hogan, @Rfq, I editted it to get rid of the "i".  Just include counter instead of i